# Why doesn't this custom created usb drive image mount?

Tags: fdisk, disk-image

I'm trying to mount a custom usb drive image created with `fdisk`. This is how I created the image:

1. Created a file of the exact same size of an old usb drive image used as a model: `dd if=/dev/zero of=image.img count=30712320` (size: `15724707840 B`, `15.7 GB`)
2. Created the partition table: in `fdisk`: `o`
3. Created the partition: in `fdisk`: `n`, `p`, `1`, `enter`, `enter`
4. Toggled the partition type to `W95 FAT 32 (LBA)`: in `fdisk`: `t`, `c`
5. Set the boot flag to on: in `fdisk`: `a`, `1`
6. Wrote the changes to the image: in `fdisk`: `w`

Output of `fdisk -l image.img`:

```
Disk image.img: 15.7 GB, 15724707840 bytes
193 heads, 9 sectors/track, 17681 cylinders, total 30712320 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0xc8fac3e1

    Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
image.img1   *        2048    30712319    15355136    c  W95 FAT32 (LBA)
```

Everything seems ok, but the problem is I'm not able to mount the image:

1) `sudo mount image.img /media/image`:

```
mount: you must specify the filesystem type
```

2) `sudo mount -t vfat image.img /media/image`:

```
mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/loop0, missing codepage or helper program, or other error
In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try dmesg | tail  or so
```

3) `sudo mount -o offset=1048576 image.img /media/image` (`1048576`=starting sector number*sector size):

```
mount: you must specify the filesystem type
```

4) `sudo mount -t vfat -o offset=1048576 image.img /media/image` (`1048576`=starting sector number*sector size):

```
mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/loop0, missing codepage or helper program, or other error
In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try dmesg | tail  or so
```

Why does this happen?